# Changing Button Attributes to Match Slider Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslider

Greets,

First - this site is incredible.  I've learned a ton of great things here!

I'm using a jquery based slider program to display a sequence of pictures (a series of books). Beneath the slider window I've positioned a "PDF" buttons. I'm trying to sort how to have the button download the file associated with whatever image is currently displayed in the slider box. So if "Picture #3" is showing in the slider window I need the PDF button to be associated with the respective #3 file. I believe I need to change each button's attributes dynamically to match what's showing in the slider window.

You can view the beta site at [beta](http://www.planetsarsfield.com/pubs/index.html)

I suspect I'll need some sort of javascript to snag the click event and feed it to the button's attributes. That's as far as my shaky legs can carry me with this one. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm a real noob at this and learning slowly so use small words!

Cheers,
TY

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. I think this would probably work, but I'm not used to culling from arrays of jQ elements.

Put the filename into an `alt` tag in your list items, then use this script:

```
$('#download-button').click( function() {
    var left_pos = $('ul').css('left');
    var win_width = $('ul').innerWidth();

    left_pos = left_pos * (-1)  /* Will convert from negative to positive */

    var slide_num = left_pos/win_width;
    var slides = $('ul').find('li');        

    $(this).attr('src', 'path/to' + slides[slide_num].attr('alt'));
});
```

Also, upon checking the living DOM while playing around with the slider, I noticed that it seemed to jump a bit if you changed directions toward the end of/beginning of the slides. You may want to investigate that

Comment: Okay - I'll starting splicing and see what happens; I see the logic of what you've written out.

Yeah, I noticed the jumping bit too... not sure what's causing it yet.  I have a felling it's a typo in my code someplace.

Cheers - TY

Comment: Well, I tried many times to get it to work... no joy.  I think one of the problems is jSlider itself - it's hard to get event handles, and with the sticking problems, as well as library conflicts, I opted to switch over to jQueryTools.  I used their "scrollable" and "tab" scripts to create a snazzy slideshow.  You can embed DIVs in the panes and it was easy to add events - there are plenty of handles and I was able to make a dynamic buttons.  No more javascript library conflicts either.  Thanks again for the help!!!